# Compute number of points having same property

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

I have been given a cuboid which has either green or red color for each point (integer coordinates) in it. 
I am also given another cuboid whose lower left corner is (x1, y1, z1) and upper right corner is (x2, y2, z2) inside this cuboid for which i need to tell the number of points having a green color. 
Additionally, I have been given the following information: 
a = number of points in [x1, x2] having green color.
b = number of points in [y1, y2] having green color.
c = number of points in [z1, z2] having green color.

I can't seem to figure out how to compute the number of points lying between (x1, y1, z1) and (x2, y2, z2) which are green in color.

Comment: Your information is unclear. Do you want to say that between (x1, y, z) and (x2,y,z), there are always exactly $a$ green points? And is a cuboid a rectangular parallelepiped? In that case, the infomation would be highly redundant, so please check your source.

Comment: Yes and yes. How is the information redundant?

Comment: If there are $a$ green points in each $x$-segment, then there are $a \cdot (y_2-y_1) \cdot (z_2-z_1)$ green points in total in the small cuboid. We do not need $b$ and $c$ here. So, possibly you want to express things only with $a,b,c$, but there is clearly a restriction missing on the actual question.

Comment: I am confused as to how it is a⋅(y2−y1)⋅(z2−z1). Can you please tell what would it be in case of a 2d grid instead of a cuboid?

Comment: What kind of question do you want to ask for the 2d grid? The envelopping cuboid in your question is also redundant. This is very, very unlikely for a contest problem to contain so much redundant information. Where is it from?

Comment: http://razimantv.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/booklet1.pdf ..Page 15 and 16

Comment: The word 'green' has not been found in the linked pdf.

Comment: Its there on page 15 and 16. Problem on 15, Solution on 16th

Comment: I see, the question does not correspond to your question at all. The points in a certain region are flipped, so you do not know the number of green points, you have to regard the parity of flips.

Comment: I use a segment tree to find the number of green points in a particular dimension. All I cant figure out is how to arrive at the formula there. Hence, the modification to the question. I am sorry I messed up

Comment: Can you please tell how to arrive at this formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I am still not sure how this relates to the original question in the link, but here goes:

If there are exactly $a$ green points between $(x_1,y,z)$ and $(x_2,y,z)$ for the relevant values $y_1\le y \le y_2$ and $z_1\le z \le z_2$, this means that we get $a$ green points for each relevant pair $(y,z)$.

So how many pairs $(y,z)$ are there with $y_1\le y \le y_2$ and $z_1\le z \le z_2$?

There are $y_2-y_1+1$ choices for $y$ and $z_2-z_1+1$ choices for $z$ and the choices are independent, so there are $(y_2-y_1+1)(z_2-z_1+1)$ pairs.

In total, we get $a\cdot(y_2-y_1+1)\cdot(z_2-z_1+1)$ green points in the region.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this really isn't the answer. Please check page 16 of the linked pdf for the correct answer. Can you please explain that?

Comment: @user1925405 It is the answer to your question here. I am quite aware that it is not at all the answer to the question in the linked pdf. I am really unable to explain to you why you asked the question you asked.

Comment: The formula in the linked pdf is all i wanted to ask, sir. I merely tried to simplify the question to remove the programming part out of it. I know I messed up. But it'd be more helpful if you could please point out how to get at the formula given in the pdf regardless of what I asked here.